# AndroidAudioConverter permission is denied using Android Q

Tags: android

Android Q has introduced some breaking changes with folder/file permissions. I get the following error when using the converter on Android:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.ltcfastpay.timecard.debug/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied

I had the same problem with the AndroidAudioRecorder and found that the following method of getting the file path was deprecated in Android Q:

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`

To fix I had to change it to:

`this.getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`

So now I am able to record and save as wav but when I try to convert to mp3 I get the permission denied.

I have tried to make changes to the AndroidAudioConverter.java file but its locked in Android Studio which tells me that I probably should not be tampering with it.

Answer (score 5):

Now If You Guys Looking For FFMPEG for ANDROID Q Here is link use below FFMPEG Build. Include this to your **app/build.gradle**

**Min SDK 24**

```
  dependencies {
        implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.3'
    }
```

**Min SDK 16**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.2.2.LTS'
}
```

tested in **OnePlus 7T**
**Android Q**

Comment: helloo, as you mentioned in your library, this is working in android 10 too. But apk size is increases to much, size increases about 70 MB!!!! You have any idea about this to reduce size?

Comment: @pratikvekariya there ar option for it. You can use according to your need. option like below

Comment: min min-gpl https https-gpl audio video full full-gpl

Comment: like this implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.4'

Comment: or else sign you apk using abb option  google willmanage size according Devices

Comment: helloo, thanks for the reply. I have implemented library as you said, i have used implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-audio:4.4' and implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-video:4.4'  but it doesn't work at all. I need to be done multiple audio trim then merge trimmed audio and then add merged audio to video(this video is silent).

Comment: Use bundle instead of apk after using this library to reduce your apk size. google will deliver native library automatically according to your device architecture.

Comment: does this library give 64 bit apk error on Play store ?

Comment: No This Library Generate 64bit  apk too

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to change the library, Just change **targetSdkVersion 29 to 28** in your `build.gradle`

It worked for me.

Comment: then you can not upload your app to the play store because the min targetSdkVersion has to be 29 or above.